# segfault while converting void * to char *

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct data{
    char *s;
} data;

void func(void *a){
    data p;
    char *chr = (char *)a;
    strcpy(p.s, (const char *)chr);
    printf("%s\n", p.s); 
}

int main(void)
{
    func((void *)100); // segfault
    return 0;
}
```

When I pass some string value it do that, but some numeric value gives segfault.

**I want that func() should accept any value irrespective of integer or string.**

Output should be:
`100`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you dereference `chr` in your function? The code you show only assigns the pointer. That can barely cause a segfault

Comment: What should be the correct code?

Comment: @kuro the pointer is not dereferenced in this code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Using some numbers as address is rarely correct unless you want to address memory mapped peripheral devices.

Comment: Provide code that shows your problem. Not some unrelated bunch of statements that you made up.

Comment: @user16656381 show **actual** code. This one will not segfault. Voting to close

Comment: Are you trying to access location 100 on a microcontroller?

Comment: @cup NO on a laptop windows 10

Comment: Your code has _undefined behavior_. It may segfault or do just about anything.

Comment: What do you expect to be at address `100` and why do you think you can use this address?

Comment: I want that func() should accept any value irrespective of integer or string.

Comment: Ah, finally you show code that can cause a segfault. You are not allowed to access any memory that you did not allocate. Either via variable definitions or via dynamic memory allocation. Accessing any other address is illegal causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user16656381 I want that func() should accept any value irrespective of integer or string.       func((void *)100);  is not a integer or string - but address of something?

Comment: *"I want that func() should accept any value"* - Could you clarify? Update the question with the output you expect from this program.

Comment: @AvalSarri So, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(void *)100` converts `100` to an address. Later you access that address as if a string is allocated there, which is very unlikely unless this happens to be some bare metal microcontroller application. Overall the code is completely nonsensical and the  reason why is that you simply *can't* program by trial & error - you actually need to know what you are doing, there can be no guessing.

Now, it would seem that what you are actually trying to do here is to write a type-generic function that can handle either a string or an integer. That should be done in completely different ways. In old style C you'd use an enum to indicate which type a `void*` points at. In modern C, we can use type-generic features with the aid of a wrapper macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func_int (int x)         { printf("%d\n", x); }
void func_str (const char* x) { puts(x); }
#define func(x) _Generic((x), int: func_int, char*: func_str)(x)

int main (void)
{
  func(100);
  func("hello");
}
```

Comment: I have to create two functions for handling int and string without `void *`.

Comment: @TusharChaurasia And what does this example look like?

Comment: Nice and efficient

Comment: @TusharChaurasia but it works only compile time

Comment: your macro can be expanded for more data types

Comment: @TusharChaurasia yes you can expand the macro for more data types. You could use my attempt at [generic print](https://github.com/jar3m/c_everything/blob/f9e92e0adc3c2c6e43d1d472b97ba13b605525ac/common/inc/generic_def.h#L43) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You get a segmentation fault because inside your function you dereference the `100` pointer (implicitly, through the `printf("%s", a)` call).

The `printf` function with `%s` argument (and `strcpy`) attempts to read from the beginning of the given location until it reaches a `\0`.

When you pass the integer `100`, you actually point to the memory location at the 100 address, making your code attempt to read from (probably) inaccessible location.

If you want to make a function in C which will automatically recognize whether a string or integer is passed, it is a little difficult.

I recommend making two functions, one for printing integers and the other for printing strings. It will make your code much cleaner, easier to use and bug-less.

Comment: yeah, was looking for syntax sugar.

Answer (score 0):

```
void func(void *a){
    data p;
    char *chr = (char *)a;
    p.s = chr;
    printf("%s : %s\n", p.s, chr); 
}
```

When you pass the arbitrary integer number converted to a pointer, this number has to be translated to the valid memory location as you access (you dereference the pointer) that location.

If the pointer is not referencing valid memory location the behaviour is **undefined** and anything can happen including the segfault.

If you want to have function which prints many types you need to pass the type as well.

```
typedef enum
{
    STRING_TYPE,
    SIGNED_INTEGER,
    UNSIGNED_INTEGER,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE,
}partype;


void mysimpleprint(partype type, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    union{
        int i;
        unsigned u;
        char *s;
        float f;
        double d;
    }data;

    va_start(va, type);
    switch(type)
    {
        case STRING_TYPE:
            data.s = va_arg(va, char *);
            puts(data.s);
            break;
        case SIGNED_INTEGER:
            data.i = va_arg(va, int);
            printf("%d", data.i);
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            data.f = va_arg(va, float);
            printf("%f", data.i);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Not implemented\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation is good but @Lundin 's code was short.

Comment: @ludin's code requires compiler to support C11 std for _Generic() macro to work

Comment: Yeah, I use C++20 by the way.

Comment: @TusharChaurasia You do not use C++,  as C++ supports polymorphism. There is no need for C "magic"

Comment: @0___________ Sorry, I mean C17